# Python - Which data structure to use?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a large array of numerical data that I need to sort, insert, and move values backwards and forwards in the sorted order. I was previously using a simple array. Now each value has to be linked with an id (a unique int, just along for the ride).

Can I extend the array class, or do I need to use a list of tuples? What is my best option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a list for the sake of having a sorted - well - list. If you want to associate additional data, you could either use a tuple to store the data, or even create a custom object for it that stores the id in an additional field.

You shouldn’t need to extend the list for that, you can just put any object into a list. For example this would be easily possible:

```
>>> lst = [ ( 132, 'foobar' ), ( 58, 'other value' ) ]
>>> lst.append( ( 70, 'some data value' ) )
>>> lst
[(132, 'foobar'), (58, 'other value'), (70, 'some data value')]
>>> lst.sort( key=lambda x: x[0] )
>>> lst
[(58, 'other value'), (70, 'some data value'), (132, 'foobar')]
>>> lst.sort( key=lambda x: x[1] )
>>> lst
[(132, 'foobar'), (58, 'other value'), (70, 'some data value')]
```

#### edit:

In case you are using Python 3.1+, you could also use the [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) type. It is an extension to the normal `dict` which maintains the order just like `list` does.

Comment: Liking this answer better for my particular situation. Maintaining a dictionary of keys would be better if all were required, but in my case the vast majority will never be used at the same time.

Comment: FYI, collections.OrderedDict is also available in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

Using lists or arrays is problematic when you need to do insertions or deletions -- these are O(n) operations which can be devastatingly slow with large datasets.

Consider using [blist](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/blist/) which has a list-like API but affords O(lg N) insertion and deletion.

Answer (score 1):

why not using a dictionary, with the key as the item of original array, and value is the id related to the key.

of course you could access it in sorted order, like this:

`a = {'key':'id'}`

`keys = a.keys()`

`keys.sort()`

`for k in keys:`

```
    print a[key]
```

Comment: This seems like the best option so far. I can let the SQL query do the initial sort, so the dictionary of indexes will be accurate. After that I shouldn't need to resort, I can just update everything on the fly.

Comment: That method obviously works, but if there's a lot of data and performance matters, it's going to be slower, since you're jumping all around in memory and so not getting caching benefits.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to poke's answer, you can use a 2d array -- but if the arrays are big, [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) is generally a good bet for any kind of numerical data in Python. Just make a 2D array that looks like

```
[ [1  614.124]
  [2  621236.139]
  [3  1243.612] ]
```

and then you can sort with [`.sort()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy.sort).